# PHP Comparing 2 Arrays For Existence of Value in Each

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have 2 arrays. I simply want to know if one of the values in array 1 is present in array 2. Nothing more than returning a boolean true or false

Example A:

```
$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('zebra','yeti','xantis');
```

Expected result = false

Example B:

```
$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('zebra','yeti','able','xantis');
```

Expected result = true

So, would it be best to use array_diff() or array_search() or some other simple PHP function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use array_intersect and check if it isn't empty.

```
$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('zebra','yeti','xantis');

echo !!array_intersect($a, $b) ? 'true' : 'false'; //false

$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('zebra','yeti','able','xantis');

echo !!array_intersect($a, $b) ? 'true' : 'false'; //true
```

Or you can make a simple function to check if there is at least one intersection. This is faster than the first one because it doesn't have to find all the intersections. When it finds one, it returns true at that moment.

```
function check_for_intersect($a, $b) {
    $c = array_flip($a);
    foreach ($b as $v) {
        if (isset($c[$v])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('zebra','yeti','xantis');

echo check_for_intersect($a, $b) ? 'true' : 'false';

$a = array('able','baker','charlie');
$b = array('able','zebra','yeti','xantis');

echo check_for_intersect($a, $b) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: Thai...I like the !!array_intersect() version. The function will work (I'm sure), but I prefer to keep my code to a minimum simply due to the basic nature of what I am trying to do with it.

Comment: empty() works great, but I like your version best Thai...thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, you can get all values of an array as keys with array_flip().

Answer (score 4):

You could do something with [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

if you want to check for a specific number of matches:

```
if (count(array_intersect($a, $b)) == 1)
{
// > 0, one or more elements from $a is also in $b
// == 1, one element matches, etc.
}
```

If you just want to see if any element is there:

```
$new = array_intersect($a, $b);

if (!empty($new)) { ... }
```

Comment: @baz, agreed, was updating my answer when you commented

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) for that!

Answer (score 0):

I found using array search

```
function check_for_intersect($a, $b)
    foreach($a as $h)
        if (array_search($h,$b) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

is much faster than doing an array_intersect when using arrays with lots of elements, because you can save lot of time searching only for the first element occurrence instead for all.